# Should I learn Lex/ YACC or FLEX/Bison

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I took compiler course last year. Now I want to learn, how to write our own *lexical analyzer* and *parser*. I searched the net came across these two tools which are under *GNU License*.

- LEX
- YACC

But there also alternative tools to these known as `FLEX` and `BISON`. I think they are under BSD License, I'm not sure. But I'm unable to figure out which tool should I learn.

Comment: Bison is released under a Gnu license. None of those other tools are. Flex is released under a modified BSD licence; byacc ("Berkeley yacc") is public domain. I honestly don't know where you would find the original source code for lex any more, but it definitely predates GNU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most novice users the tools are almost identical. The same input source will build a lexer/parser that performs the same task. There are differences, but none that would impair your ability to learn and use the tools. The differences would only be of interest to those more experienced coders or those that like to focus on the esoteric internal operations of tools.

Just use which ever one works best for you in your software environment. I teach my students using flex and bison on the basis that they can experience the same tools irrespective of platform (Windows, linux, OSX etc).

Comment: So I should go with FLEX and BISON I think.